# How to filter properties on a self reference using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Let's say I have a class like this that I want to serialize with Jackson.

```
public class Product {
    int id;
    String name;
    List<Product> similarProducts;
}
```

How do I end up with something like this?

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product 1",
    "similarProducts": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Product 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Product 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've see how to use @JsonProperty to do this by class or @JsonView to select things too but that also seems like it's by class (am I mistaken)? I'm not sure how to get this to work when I have a class that's referencing itself and the parent has many properties, while the child only has a few.

Imagine this is an ecommerce site and you want to get the name and URL of similar products from a single JSON payload, but you don't need any other details of those similar products (children).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize using `@JsonFilter` annotation.

New version of your model:

```
public class Product {
    int id;
    String name;

    @JsonFilter("productView")
    List<Product> similarProducts;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Serialization process:

```
 FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
            .addFilter(
                "productView", 
                SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("similarProducts")
            );
 String res = new ObjectMapper()
            .writer(filters)
            .writeValueAsString(product);
 System.out.println(res);
```

**Example**

Code:

```
Product child1 = new Product();
child1.id = 2;
child1.name = "sfd";
Product grandchild1 = new Product();
grandchild1.id = 4;
grandchild1.name = "werrwe";
child1.similarProducts = Collections.singletonList(grandchild1);
Product child2 = new Product();
child2.id = 2;
child2.name = "sfd";

Product product = new Product();
product.id = 1;
product.name = "product";

product.similarProducts = Arrays.asList(child1, child2);

FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("productView",
            SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("similarProducts"));

String res = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            .writer(filters)
            .writeValueAsString(product);

System.out.println(res);
```

Output:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "product",
  "similarProducts" : [ {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "sfd"
   }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "sfd"
   } ]
}
```

**See also**

Blog post about filtering properties in jackson: [Every day Jackson usage, part 3: Filtering properties](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html)

Comment: Your example helps me a lot as I'd seen filters but wasn't exactly sure how to apply them or if they were right for me. I found that `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(...)` was perfect for my use case since I want to whitelist vs blacklist. If I have a global / shared ObjectMapper() for performance, would it be appropriate to add many filters to it for many unrelated views or would that slow down performance for views that didn't use filters?

Comment: @jon_wu I am glad that my answer was helpful. :) Regarding filter performance I can't say for sure, but skimming over the source code shows that performance should not suffer. Look at the [line 153](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.5.3/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializer.java#153) of the source code: if filter is absent, no additional code is invoked.

Comment: That's great. In addition, it looks like creating a writer with filters is pretty cheap so it won't really speed things up to reuse the `ObjectWriter()` too much according to the docs I just checked out: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonBestPracticesPerformance

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish this with a custom Serializer if you ALWAYS want this behavior (seems in this case it could be dangerous to not include the filter since errors will result in the self reference case)

Model:

```
public class Product {
    public int id;
    public String name;

    @JsonSerialize(contentUsing=ProductSerializer.class)
    public List<Product> similarProducts = Lists.newArrayList();
}
```

Serializer:

```
public class ProductSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Product> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Product product, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", product.id);
        jgen.writeStringField("name", product.name);
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Product p1 = new Product();
Product p2 = new Product();
p1.similarProducts = Lists.newArrayList(p2);
p2.similarProducts = Lists.newArrayList(p1);
p1.id = 1;
p2.id = 2;
p1.name = "p1";
p2.name = "p2";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(p1));
```

Output:

```
{"id":1,"name":"p1","similarProducts":[{"id":2,"name":"p2"}]}
```

The drawback with this approach is that you would need to add new properties to the serializer as they are added.